# Javascript filter object using includes

Tags: javascript, object, filter, include

I'm trying to filter an object using the filter() function in javascript .

I want to filter againts an array like this: [1615, 1616]. It's referenced in the code as value.verdier.

Dataset is a large array holding objects that have several properties, parsed from a JSON string. Each object in the array has a property named kat_id.

The goal is to reduce the array so that it only holds objects where kat_id=1615 or kat_id=1616. Or any other value that I have in value.verdier.

My code is like this:

```
dataset = dataset.filter(function (el) 
     {
        return value.verdier.includes(el.kat_id );
     });
```

I'm problably missing something really obvious.

Comment: Yes, I see that the question was poorly written. I shall edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal is to reduce the array so that it only holds objects where kat_id=1615 or kat_id=1616. Or any other value that I have in `value.verdier`.

The code in your question will do that, if the `kat_id` values and the values in `value.verdier` are all *numbers* or all *strings*. That's because `includes` does a `===` between the thing you pass into it and the entries in the array you call it on. So `[1, 2, 3].includes("2")` is `false`, as is `["1", "2", "3"].includes(2)`.

I assume you wouldn't be posting the question if it were working, though, so I assume the type of the values of `kat_id` and the type of the values in `value.verdier` are different — one of them is a number, the other is a string.

**If** the `kat_id` values are strings and the `value.verdier` values are numbers, you need to parse `kat_id` to number before using `includes`:

```
return value.verdier.includes(parseInt(el.kat_id, 10));
```

Live Example:

```js
var value = {
    verdier: [1615, 1616]
};

var dataset = [
    {kat_id: "1", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "2", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "1615", expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: "3", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "1616", expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: "4", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "5", expected: "omit"},
];
dataset = dataset.filter(function (el) 
{
    return value.verdier.includes(parseInt(el.kat_id, 10));
});
console.log(dataset);
```

Or if the `kat_id` values are numbers and the `value.verdier` values are strings, you need to convert the `kat_id` numbers to strings before using `includes`:

```
return value.verdier.includes(String(el.kat_id));
```

Live Example:

```js
var value = {
    verdier: ["1615", "1616"]
};

var dataset = [
    {kat_id: 1, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 2, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 1615, expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: 3, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 1616, expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: 4, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 5, expected: "omit"},
];
dataset = dataset.filter(function (el) 
{
    return value.verdier.includes(String(el.kat_id));
});
console.log(dataset);
```

If the values *vary* (some `kat_id`s are strings and others are numbers, and/or some `value.verdier` values are strings and others are numbers), you probably need `some` rather than `includes` and a type-insensitive comparison:

```
return value.verdier.some(function(val) { return String(val) === String(el.kat_id); });
```

Live Example:

```js
var value = {
    verdier: [1615, "1616"]
};

var dataset = [
    {kat_id: "1", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 2, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "1615", expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: "3", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 1616, expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: "4", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 5, expected: "omit"},
];
dataset = dataset.filter(function (el) 
{
    return value.verdier.some(function(val) { return String(val) === String(el.kat_id); });
});
console.log(dataset);
```

---

I've stuck with ES5-level code above because your question seemed to be using ES5-level code only. But here are those examples using ES2015+:

```
dataset = dataset.filter(el => value.verdier.includes(parseInt(el.kat_id, 10)));
```

```js
const value = {
    verdier: [1615, 1616]
};

let dataset = [
    {kat_id: "1", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "2", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "1615", expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: "3", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "1616", expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: "4", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "5", expected: "omit"},
];
dataset = dataset.filter(el => value.verdier.includes(parseInt(el.kat_id, 10)));
console.log(dataset);
```

```
dataset = dataset.filter(el => value.verdier.includes(String(el.kat_id)));
```

```js
const value = {
    verdier: ["1615", "1616"]
};

let dataset = [
    {kat_id: 1, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 2, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 1615, expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: 3, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 1616, expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: 4, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 5, expected: "omit"},
];
dataset = dataset.filter(el => value.verdier.includes(String(el.kat_id)));
console.log(dataset);
```

```
dataset = dataset.filter(el => value.verdier.some(val => String(val) === String(el.kat_id)));
```

```js
const value = {
    verdier: [1615, "1616"]
};

let dataset = [
    {kat_id: "1", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 2, expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: "1615", expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: "3", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 1616, expected: "retain"},
    {kat_id: "4", expected: "omit"},
    {kat_id: 5, expected: "omit"},
];
dataset = dataset.filter(el => value.verdier.some(val => String(val) === String(el.kat_id)));
console.log(dataset);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the incredibly friendly and helpful answer! Yes el.kat_id was a string, parseInt did fix the issue.

Comment: @johnohod - I'm really glad that helped! It was the only thing I could think of that would account for what you were describing. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working sample:

```js
function isInRefList(value) {
  let refList = [5, 44, 560];
  return refList.includes(value); //returns boolean
}

var myarr = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44];
myarr = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isInRefList);

console.log(myarr); //Prints filtered array
```